# kendo ui angular save grid settings

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

We have a new application that we are creating using Angular based on an existing application that uses AngularJS. In the existing app we are using Kendo UI and users are able to save their grid settings.  I was not able to find similar functionality in the Kendo UI Angular Grid.  Is saving of user grid settings something that is supported in the Kendo UI Angular Grid?

Answer (score 0):

You Can save "state" for future use. The Example is given below.

https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-refresh-angular-kendo-grid.

It hold below given datas(This is just show you, initially it look like this).

public state: State = { filter: undefined, group: [], skip: 0, sort: [], take: 0 };