# Is there any way to get the full state of a kendo angular(2) grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I'd like to be able to access the internal state that kendo keeps, so I can take a 'snapshot' of the grid and load it later. Is this possible?

Something like:

```
class SomeGridComponent {
  public grid: GridComponent;  


  // (onDataStateChange)="onDataStateChangeHandler($event)"
  onDataStateChangeHandler(event) {

    // get the full state including sorts, groups, etc.
    const fullGridState = this.grid.getOptions();  // I noticed a similar method in kendo jquery grid
  }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you include in 'full state'? You can get the filters, groups, sort and paging via the [DataStateChangeEvent](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/DataStateChangeEvent/).

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Just follow below given link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46350317/kendo-ui-angular-save-grid-settings/51258374#51258374